# Prevent Duplicate ID in Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to prevent a duplicate ID from being created within the database.

I have added this as per other examples:

```
select * from users where NOT EXISTS(select * from users where users.username = ?)";
```

but it doesnt seem to work and it provides me with this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Any help is appreciated, or the solution would be very helpful, im a php learner (novice).

Here is the code i'm working with:

```
<?php

 class Users {
 public $username = null;
 public $password = null;
 public $salt = "************************hidden*****************************";

 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
     if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
 }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
    //store the parameters
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }

 public function userLogin() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if( $valid ) {
            $success = true;
        }

        $con = null;
        return $success;
     }catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         return $success;
     }
 }

 public function register() {
    $correct = false;
        try {
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password) select * from users where NOT EXISTS(select * from users where users.username = ?)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
     }

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to prevent duplicate entries, Why don't you make that column as 'PRIMARY' or 'UNIQUE' ?

Comment: Set ID in the users table to Primary?

Comment: yes, make ID as PRIMARY, That way it will prevent duplicate entries.

Comment: If there are multiple constraints, you don't want to have to parse the SQL error message.

Comment: I am trying to do this now, ill get back shortly

Comment: sorry for being a little dub.. LOL! Is this right? I added PRIMARY to the username line

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` PRIMARY varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varbinary(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

Comment: you want to prevent duplicates in ID right? So add PRIMARY  to the userID field.

Comment: added primary, still creates a new database entry using the same username

Comment: @DeZéroToxin: Usually *usernames* are supposed to be unique as well. qldguy27au, keep `userID` as your primary key, but add a `UNIQUE` key to the `username` field. It looks like you've added a compound primary key on both `userID` *and* `username`. That means they must be unique *together* which is not what you want.

Comment: yes, @Mark is correct. for eg. we use email addresses as usernames, where it is unique. So you must change UserID to PRIMARY and Username to UNIQUE.

Comment: @DeZéroToxin: email addresses are not unique btw. `abc@gmail.com` is the same as `abc+d@gmail.com` is the same as `a.b.c@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Will it not be easier to run a Query with the id you want to insert and if it returns empty you insert else display an error

Comment: You can set d id to auto increment and dat way you dont need to worry it will auto generate

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password) select * from users where NOT EXISTS(select * from users where users.username = ?)";
```

You can't just tack random bits of SQL onto other bits of SQL and expect it to work.

The error you are getting,

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Means you've mixed `:parameters` with `?` parameters. If you reread your SQL statement you will see that it contains both. But that's kind of moot, because it's not valid SQL.

If you want to enforce the username to be unique, give it a UNIQUE key. This will cause a database error when you try to insert another user with the same username. You will have to handle this error in your register() function and give a meaningful message back to the user.

If you want to check if that username exists before attempting to create the new user account, you can write a query like

```
 SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?)
```

This will return back a 1 if the username is taken, 0 otherwise.

If you are not familiar with how to run this query, you should do some more reading on PHP, PDO and MySQL.

Comment: im learning, i wrote the code, it works as it is, but im not a coder with 50 years experience, its just going to take soe time to get this working, ill keep at it with tutorials etc until i fully understand where ive gone wrong. thank you though

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to come off condescending, it just looked like you copied and pasted a snippet of code you found elsewhere.